# VMWare Workstation Can't See Wifi?

Tags: ubuntu, wireless-networking, virtual-machine, vmware, kubuntu

I'm running Kubuntu 18.04 and attempting to use a bridged connection with VMWare Workstation. So far, I haven't been able to use my internal wifi card inside the emulated operating systems. It simply doesn't appear. I've seen various ways to fix this on windows versions of the VMware workstation (by setting the bridge type to the wi-fi card), but there appears to be no such feature on the ubuntu release. How can I get this functionality on Kubuntu?

In the emulated OS, the network appears as a wired connection.

Comment: Are you hoping to use some Wi-Fi-specific tool within the guest OS? I mean, if the guest OS is already getting connectivity via the host OS’s Wi-Fi interface, who cares that is shows as an emulated Ethernet connection rather than a native Wi-Fi connection?

Comment: @Spiff Unfortunately, yes. I need to use Windows XP's Windows Connect Now Feature to configure our printer, which generates a config file for a USB to sign in to our internet connection. Windows XP must sign on to the network to do this.